Why are the closures of $(0,1)$ and $(0,+\infty)$ not homeomorphic despite the intervals themselves being homeomorphic?
It is well known that the interval $(0,1)$ is homeomorphic to $(0,+\infty)$.
However, considering their closures, we have:

The closure of $(0,1)$ is $[0,1]$, which is compact.
The closure of $(0,+\infty)$ is $[0,+\infty)$, which is not compact.

I am confused because homeomorphism implies that topological properties should be preserved, and compactness is a topological property. How can this discrepancy be explained?

Homeomorphism preserves the topological properties of a space, not of its closure as a subspace of an arbitrary larger topological space.  $(0,1)$ (and similarly $(0,\infty)$) can have various (non-homeomorphic) closures, in various spaces of which it is a subspace. For instance the closure of $(0,1)$ in $S^1$ (via $t\mapsto e^{2i\pi t}$) is $S^1$.

Possibly useful here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4855136/25554 which begins “Your confusion is a common one. You haven't realized that "closure" is a “relative” concept. This means that it's not quite correct to talk about ‘the’ closure of a set $$”.

As spinosarus123's answer already explains, closure is something that applies to subspaces of some given space, in this case $\mathbb{R}$. As such, there is no reason to expect a homeomorphism from $A$ to $B$ to extend to a homeomorphism (or even a map) between their closures as subspaces of some space, since this depends on the ambient space. There is, however, a situation in which homeomorphisms preserve closure, namely if you're starting out with a homeomorphism of the ambient space that restricts to a homeomorphism on $A$ and $B$.
In your particular case, you should therefore only expect compatibility with closures if you're given a homeomorphism $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ to begin with, and there's no such homeomorphism mapping $(0, 1)$ to $(0, \infty)$.

As the example in your post amply demonstrates, using two different subsets of the topological space $X = \mathbb R$, the "closure of $A$ in $X$" is not a topological property of $A$: it also depends on $X$.
What one can say in this situation is that the closure is a topological property of a space-and-a-subset. That is, given a space $X$ and a subset $A$, and given another space $B$ and a subset $Y$, if there exists a homeomorphism $h : X \to Y$ such that $h(A)=B$ then the closure of $A$ in $X$ is homeomorphic to the closure of $B$ in $Y$. So in that situation it would be true that the closure of $A$ in $X$ is compact if and only if the closure of $B$ in $Y$ is compact.
So for the example in your post, one can reach an interesting conclusion: there does not exist a homeomorphism $h : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $h(0,1)=(0,\infty)$.

Lee Mosher, indeed there is no such automorphism of $\mathbb R$ that maps either an open bounded interval to an open unbounded interval or a closed bounded interval to a closed unbounded interval right?

That is correct.

But the point of my last sentence is that the nonexistence of such an automorphism is an immediate consequence of the fact that the closures of $(0,1)$ and $(0,\infty)$ in $\mathbb R$ are not homeomorphic.

The closure of these spaces are homeomorphic. The closure of the space $(0,1)$ is $(0,1)$ and the closure of the space $(0,\infty)$ is $(0,\infty)$.
The thing you are referring to as closure is the closure of the set $(0,1)$ as a subset of the space $\mathbb{R}$. This closure is indeed $[0,1]$, however this is not intrinsic to the space $(0,1)$.

Perhaps it'd be more careful to say that the closure of a space is simply undefined, although we can consider the closure of the entire set as a subspace (which is always itself).
